# How could I get a single array of coordinates using MapBox?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, fetch, data-visualization, mapbox

I have an array of 55 countries:

`countries = ['Albania', 'Turkey', .....]`

And I am looking to get a single array in the following form:

`letlocations = [ ["Albania", 11.8166, 122.0942], ["Turkey", 11.9804, 121.9189], ..... ];`

At the moment I have only been able to work with 1 location by using this code

```html
const changeMapCenter = async () => {
    const searchLocation = ['Madrid', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Mexico City', 'Chicago', 'Munich', 'Machu Pichu']
    let item = searchLocation[Math.floor(Math.random() * searchLocation.length)];
    const searchURL = `${MAPBOX_PLACES_API}${item}${REST_PLACES_URL}`
    const response = await fetch(searchURL)
    const data = await response.json()
    const result = data
    const { coordinates } = result.features[0].geometry
    const features = { coordinates }
    const latlong = [...coordinates].reverse()
    mymap.flyTo(latlong)
    L.marker(latlong).bindPopup(`hola estás en ${item}`).addTo(mymap)
}
```

My question is how could I plot several countries at the same time?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Start by researching `Promise.all`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all